# Phonecall on_change_opportunity, change opportunities date_action

Tags: python, odoo

We have the on_change_opportunity method in crm.phonecall.py. I was wondering (and trying) to make that if you add an opportunity to a scheduled call, that opportunity's date_action(Next action date) turns into Scheduled Call's Date.

```
def on_change_opportunity(self, cr, uid, ids, opportunity_id, context=None):
    values = {}
    if opportunity_id:
        opportunity = self.pool.get('crm.lead').browse(cr, uid, opportunity_id, context=context)
        values = {
            'section_id' : opportunity.section_id and opportunity.section_id.id or False,
            'partner_phone' : opportunity.phone,
            'partner_mobile' : opportunity.mobile,
            'partner_id' : opportunity.partner_id and opportunity.partner_id.id or False,
        }
    return {'value' : values}
```

I tried to add a line:
`opportunity.date_action = self.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`
Which clearly didn't work. How to proceed?

EDIT. The error i get is `AttributeError: 'crm.phonecall' object has no attribute '_ids'`

Comment: No. self.date wont work since you are using api 7. try first doing this:   phonecall = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)

    if phonecall:

    date = phonecall[0].date

now try to add that date to opportunity and tell me if it worked. Take care since as a comment i cant give you the tabulattion needed for coding..

Comment: @dccdany Tried this, didn't work : / [picture of my code](http://i.imgur.com/K35jufD.png)

Comment: You are mixing api 7 with 8, you cant set the date like that in 7:

opportunity.write(cr, uid, {'date_action':date}) instead of opportunity.date_action = date.

Anyway try to add some logs before and after the if and show me the values, but that should work

Comment: @dccdany `TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)` opportunity.write = `def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None)`

Comment: Try without cr and uid, and try with (cr, uid, ids, {'date_action':date}, context)

Comment: worked w/o cr and uid with just `({'date_action':date})`

Comment: Nice, want me to post it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_change_opportunity(self, cr, uid, ids, opportunity_id, context=None):
values = {}
if opportunity_id:
    opportunity = self.pool.get('crm.lead').browse(cr, uid, opportunity_id, context=context)
    values = {
        'section_id' : opportunity.section_id and opportunity.section_id.id or False,
        'partner_phone' : opportunity.phone,
        'partner_mobile' : opportunity.mobile,
        'partner_id' : opportunity.partner_id and opportunity.partner_id.id or False,
    }

    phonecall = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    if phonecall:
        date = phonecall[0].date
        opportunity.write({'date_action': date})

return {'value' : values}
```